# Get json data from a htttp based web service C#

Tags: c#, json

I can't recieve json data from the http web service, because the of data size - i guess - which is 7 MB, i first tried this :

```
private async Task<string> GetResponse(string url)
{
    HttpResponseMessage response = null;
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    try
    {
        response = await client.GetAsync(url);
    }
    catch (Exception )
    {
        throw;
    }
    return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

but it gives me "Task canceled Exception", after doing some search , i found it might be the request timeout limit probleme, so i implemented the second solution by setting the Timeout limit to two minutes :

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 2, 0);
```

when executing, there is no result, no exception and the app blocks at the method

```
client.GetAsync(url);
```

Comment: First question is, are you able to access the url via the browser. does it render? does it take time? Longer than the time specified in code? What is the actual error? did you try to inspect the Exception? your code does not reflect this besides catching an exception and throwing it.

Comment: Do you mean that it awaits for *more* than 2 minutes? Is the service you call that slow?

Comment: How many concurrent calls do you make to the *same* service? There is a limit of 2 concurrent requests per domain that is enforced by all browsers *and* .NET. Additional requests will wait for any existing requests to finish before executing. You can change this with a configuration setting on your client

Comment: Yes url is accecible and take too much time to render, i've set 10, 5 and 2 minutes to the timeout property , as i already said  'Task canceled Exception' is the only exception i get , and i yes i've inspected the exception and the message is the same.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yes it is so slow, some times it takes 4~5 minutes, i am making one request

Comment: So what is the question? If the service takes 10 minutes to respond, and you set a timeout of more than 10 minutes, your code will wait until it receives a response in 10 minutes. If you set it for less, the timeout will expire and you'll get this well-defined exception. This is normal behavior.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos is there anyway to optimise that ?

Comment: Are you asking if there is a way to optimize the other service? Because your code is waiting for that other service. It is *NOT* blocking - `await` means that the current thread is released and execution will continue when the other service responds